# asp.net - how to display a field from data row that is in html format

Tags: asp.net

I have a field of text in html format, in a row of data that I need to select and then display it in a aspx page as html.

The text contains html tags, symbols like & ; etc... and of course lots of double quotes. For example....

```
<li>products</li>Check out our full line of these products, bla bla bla....<br><a href="http://www.thiswebsite3223.com/thispage.aspx" target="_blank"><font color="blue">View</font></a><td bgcolor="#000000" align="center"><b><font color="#FFFFFF">Diameter</font><li>30&deg; Helix<li></td>
```

...etc

The method that I am trying to use to retrieve it with in the codebehind, gives me the error...

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>        Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '='.

```
    public void GetHtml()
    {
        string gethtml = Request.QueryString["product"];
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT htmlpull FROM ejn_html WHERE newseries LIKE = @gethtml";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@gethtml", SqlDbType.VarChar, 70).Value = gethtml;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt2);

        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt2.Rows)
        {
            pulledhtml = dtRow[0].ToString();
        }

    }
```

The exception is triggered on the line that contains... `sda.Fill(dt2);`

In my aspx page I try to call the variable using...

```
<%= pulledhtml %>
```

This works fine when I try to retrieve any other string variables that contain normal alphanumeric characters. This is a very large database that I inherited and I am not allowed nor would I want to edit the html in those fields.

How can I retrieve this html code and display it without exception errors?

Comment: what is your `gethtml` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql text is incorrect

```
SELECT htmlpull FROM ejn_html WHERE newseries LIKE = @gethtml
```

is invalid.  you can't use LIKE and = together.

Change you sql to either

```
SELECT htmlpull FROM ejn_html WHERE newseries = @gethtml
```

for an exact match or

```
SELECT htmlpull FROM ejn_html WHERE newseries LIKE @gethtml
```

where you define the parameter value with wildcards

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gethtml", SqlDbType.VarChar, 70).Value = "%" + gethtml + "%";
```

for a match where the value of gethtml is contained in the column value.

Comment: You are right. Wow, I am embarrassed. Thank you for the help :)